# Разместить php в тексте одной строкой

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Мне надо сделать один текст, который будет размещаться на всех страницах, но в тексте будет вставка с названием товара аналогичным той странице на которой находится.

Размещаю в файле `description.php`, который находится в папке `single product`, текст:

```
Приобретая товар
<?php the_title( '<p class="product_title entry-title">', '</p>'  ); ?>
сегодня, вы получаете скидку 10% на все
последующие покупки в нашем магазине.
```

И все работает, но название товара пишет с новой строки и последующий текст тоже.

Как можно решить это? Чтоб текст был сплошным.

Comment: вместо p поставь span

Comment: ну или сделай стиль `display:inline-block;`, для тега `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php the_title( '<span class="product_title entry-title">', '</span>'  ); ?>
```

Может так получится то, что нужно?